# Basic Vue store with with dependent API calls throughout the app

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I tried asking this question in the Vue Forums with no response, so I am going to try repeating it here:

I have an app where clients login and can manage multiple accounts (websites). In the header of the app, there’s a dropdown where the user can select the active account, and this will affect all of the components in the app that display any account-specific information.

Because this account info is needed in components throughout the app, I tried to follow the store example shown here (Vuex seemed like overkill in my situation):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

In my src/main.js, I define this:

```
Vue.prototype.$accountStore = {
  accounts: [],
  selectedAccountId: null,
  selectedAccountDomain: null
}
```

And this is my component to load/change the accounts:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="hasMoreThanOneAccount">
    <select v-model="accountStore.selectedAccountId" v-on:change="updateSelectedAccountDomain">
      <option v-for="account in accountStore.accounts" v-bind:value="account.id" :key="account.id">
        {{ account.domain }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'AccountSelector',
  data: function () {
    return {
      accountStore: this.$accountStore,
      apiInstance: new this.$api.AccountsApi()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateSelectedAccountDomain: function () {
      this.accountStore.selectedAccountDomain = this.findSelectedAccountDomain()
    },
    findSelectedAccountDomain: function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.accountStore.accounts.length; i++) {
        var account = this.accountStore.accounts[i]
        if (account.id === this.accountStore.selectedAccountId) {
          return account.domain
        }
      }

      return 'invalid account id'
    },
    loadAccounts: function () {
      this.apiInstance.getAccounts(this.callbackWrapper(this.accountsLoaded))
    },
    accountsLoaded: function (error, data, response) {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
      } else {
        this.accountStore.accounts = data
        this.accountStore.selectedAccountId = this.accountStore.accounts[0].id
        this.updateSelectedAccountDomain()
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    hasMoreThanOneAccount: function () {
      return this.accountStore.accounts.length > 1
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.loadAccounts()
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

To me this doesn’t seem like the best way to do it, but I’m really not sure what the better way is. One problem is that after the callback, I set the accounts, then the selectedAccountId, then the selectedAccountDomain manually. I feel like selectedAccountId and selectedDomainId should be computed properties, but I’m not sure how to do this when the store is not a Vue component.

The other issue I have is that until the selectedAccountId is loaded for the first time, I can’t make any API calls in any other components because the API calls need to know the account ID. However, I’m not sure what the best way is to listen for this change and then make API calls, both the first time and when it is updated later.

Comment: Would you use the store for more than one components?

Comment: One component changes the two values in the store, and the other components all just need to read the values when they're updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you seem to use `store` to simply hold values. But the real power of the Flux/Store pattern is actually realized when you centralize logic within the store as well. If you sprinkle store-related logic across components throughout the app, eventually it will become harder and harder to maintain because such logic cannot be reused and you have to traverse the component tree to reach the logic when fixing bugs.

If I were you, I will create a store by

- Defining 'primary data', then
- Defining 'derived data' that can be derived from primary data, and lastly,
- Defining 'methods' you can use to interact with such data.

IMO, the 'primary data' are `user`, `accounts`, and `selectedAccount`. And the 'derived data' are `isLoggedIn`, `isSelectedAccountAvailable`, and `hasMoreThanOneAccount`. As a Vue component, you can define it like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";

export default new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      accounts: [],
      selectedAccount: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      return this.user !== null;
    },
    isSelectedAccountAvailable() {
      return this.selectedAccount !== null;
    },
    hasMoreThanOneAccount() {
      return this.accounts.length > 0;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login(username, password) {
      console.log("performing login");
      if (username === "johnsmith" && password === "password") {
        console.log("committing user object to store and load associated accounts");
        this.user = {
          name: "John Smith",
          username: "johnsmith",
          email: "john.smith@somewhere.com"
        };
        this.loadAccounts(username);
      }
    },
    loadAccounts(username) {
      console.log("load associated accounts from backend");
      if (username === "johnsmith") {
        // in real code, you can perform check the size of array here
        // if it's the size of one, you can set selectedAccount here
        // this.selectedAccount = array[0];

        console.log("committing accounts to store");
        this.accounts = [
          {
            id: "001234",
            domain: "domain001234"
          },
          {
            id: "001235",
            domain: "domain001235"
          }
        ];
      }
    },
    setSelectedAccount(account) {
      this.selectedAccount = account;
    }
  }
});
```

Then, you can easily `import` this store in any Vue component, and start referencing values, or call methods, from this store.

For example, suppose you are creating a `Login.vue` component, and that component should redirect when `user` object becomes available within a store, you can achieve this by doing the following:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="username"><br/>
    <input type="password" v-model="password"><br/>
    <button @click="submit">Log-in</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import store from '../basic-store';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: 'johnsmith',
      password: 'password'
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      return store.isLoggedIn;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    isLoggedIn(newVal) {
      if (newVal) { // if computed value from store evaluates to 'true'
        console.log("moving on to Home after successful login.");
        this.$router.push({ name: "home" });
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      store.login(this.username, this.password);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In addition, with `isSelectedAccountAvailable` we compute, we can easily disable/enable button on the screen, to prevent user from making API calls until an account is selected:

```html
<button :disabled="!isSelectedAccountAvailable" @click="performAction()">make api call</button>
```

If you want to see the whole project, you can access it from this runnable [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8n9w63q86j). Pay attention at how `basic-store.js` is defined and used in `Login.vue` and `Home.vue`. And, if you'd like, you can also see how store is defined in `vuex` by taking a peek at `store.js`.

Good luck!

---

**Updated:**
About how you should organize dependent/related API calls, the answer is actually right in front of you. If you take a closer look at the store, you'll notice that my `login()` method subsequently calls `this.loadAccounts(username)` once the login succeeds. So, basically, you have all the flexibility to chain/nested API calls in store's methods to accommodate your business rules. The `watch()` is there simply because the UI needs to perform navigation based on change(s) made in the `store`. For most simple data changes, computed properties will suffice.

Further, from how I designed it, the reason `watch()` is used in `<Login>` component is twofold:

1. Separation of concerns: for me who has been working on server-side code for years, I'd like my `view`-related code to be cleanly separated from `model`. By restricting navigation logic inside a component, my `model` in a `store` doesn't need to know/care about navigation at all.
2. However, even if I don't separate concerns, it will still be pretty hard to import `vue-router` into my `store`. This is because my `router.js` already imports `basic-store.js` to perform [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards) preventing unauthenticated users from accessing `<Home>` component:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!store.isLoggedIn && to.name !== "login") {
    console.log(`redirect to 'login' instead of '${to.name}'.`);
    next({ name: "login" });
  } else {
    console.log(`proceed to '${to.name}' normally.`);
    next();
  }
});
```

And, because javascript doesn't support cyclic dependency yet (e.g., `router` imports `store`, and `store` imports `router`), to keep my code acyclic, my store can't perform route navigations.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This answer is awesome. So if I wanted to trigger other API calls based on a value in the store being set from one API call, I would 'watch' a computed property that depended on the store? Is this the most efficient way to do this? I remember the docs saying something about watch being heavier than computed, but I guess it's necessary here?

Comment: @srchulo The response is a bit long so I decided to add that to the answer itself. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, so here you don't actually use Vuex, you just use a Vue component as the store?

Comment: @srchulo Of course. Since in your question you mentioned that Vuex seems like overkill, and you took all the trouble to implement a custom store, I answered it that way. But, knowing that you will want to use Vuex at some point, I also left `store.js` in the codesandbox project for you to look at.

And this isn't necessarily a bad thing: internally Vuex is implemented with Vue component. So, all the concepts map nicely from one to the other: `data` maps to `state`, `computed` maps to `getters`, etc., so this Vue component will serve as a gentle introduction to Vuex for you. :)

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. I think I will use Vuex, but this example and your explanation actually helped me understand it a lot better :)